# the import com.google.maps cannot be resolved (clustering.Cluster)

Tags: android, google-maps

I am trying to use clustering in my application. However on the import statements I get 'the import com.google.maps cannot be resolved (clustering.Cluster).

Also, when using ClusterManager I get 'cannot be resolved to a type'.

The rest of the google play services are working fine.

Answer (score 4):

Are you using Android Studio, or Eclipse? Might need to check your gradle file (Android Studio for example) to see if you have the library/module dependencies lined up. If you are using this library (https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils) for example, your gradle file should have something like :

```
    dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.3+'
}
```